# What does 'Day trading' means?

Tags: word-usage

Does it means buying cheap/sales stuff?

...

From quora forums:

What things are just not worth the effort?

I have repeatedly tried all three of these:

**Day trading.** It’s like sitting in a burning house, waiting for the fire to put itself out. Your mind will refuse to think about anything else all day, hoping you’ll scrape together those few extra %. Just make solid long-term picks and forget about them.

Online dating. You need a clever profile, a ton of swipes, a clever opening line and tell the same story 75 times. That’s a lot of work only to find out they’re boring in real life. Just live your life and keep your eyes open so you’ll actually see whoever comes along.
Calorie counting. You’ll either feel bad about your food or yourself. You won’t be present while you eat, thinking about all the data. Eating is...

Comment: Have you tried looking the phrase up?

Comment: You apparently didn't even Google the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Day Trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_trading) is

> speculation in securities, specifically buying and selling financial instruments within the same trading day, such that all positions are closed before the market closes for the trading day.

With the growth of the internet it's become possible for individuals to participate in the securities markets, where they attempt to make money from small fluctuations in securities prices.